# How to write Yii extensions? Any good reference?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

Does anyone know any good reference on how to write Yii framework extensions? I've been searching all over the net and I couldn't find anything.

If there is no such thing, what steps do I need to take (in general) ?

Comment: http://ifdattic.com/create-yii-extension-by-example-eprism/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

look at the official tutorial

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.create

I think that is quite enough and good start for creating Yii Extensions

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I wonder why I wasn't able to find it... Thanks

Comment: Another forum post from a core dev: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/19538-guidelines-for-extensions